# Why is my laptop not working after switching memory sticks?

Tags: laptop, memory

Just for curiosity, I tried to switch ram sticks position to see if the laptop would still work but it does not.

**What I did:**
My laptop has exactly 2 mem slots. I removed the memory sticks and re-installed them in the opposite slot.

I switched them back to their initial slots and now the laptop is working, but the thing is I can not understand what went wrong. The order of placing the sticks should not matter since there are only 2 slots and I'm using exactly 2 memory sticks...

**These are the specs of my 2 memory installation:**

```bsh
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 11
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 4GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: SODIMM Synchronous 667 MHz (1.5 ns)
             product: M471B5773DH0-CH9
             vendor: Samsung
             physical id: 0
             serial: 67294733
             slot: DDRIII 1
             size: 2GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 667MHz (1.5ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: SODIMM Synchronous 533 MHz (1.9 ns)
             vendor: 0000
             physical id: 1
             serial: 00000000
             slot: DDRIII 2
             size: 2GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 533MHz (1.9ns)
```

**And here you can read my system specs:**

```bsh
    description: Notebook
    product: LIFEBOOK S760
    vendor: FUJITSU
    version: 10601155991
    serial: DSBF062104
    width: 4294967295 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.6 dmi-2.6 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: administrator_password=disabled boot=normal chassis=notebook keyboard_password=disabled power-on_password=disabled uuid=FF65BB3E-5F04-11E2-B153-8C736E7B1E1F
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: FJNB20A
       vendor: FUJITSU
       physical id: 0
       version: D3
       serial: I1 4TKE
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: FUJITSU // Phoenix Technologies Ltd.
          physical id: 0
          version: Version 1.21
          date: 01/24/2011
          size: 144KiB
          capacity: 2496KiB
          capabilities: pci pcmcia pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppy720 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb biosbootspecification netboot
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 520  @ 2.40GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 4
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 520  @ 2.40GHz
          slot: Onboard
          size: 1651MHz
          capacity: 2400MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 133MHz
          capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes lahf_lm pti tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid dtherm ida arat cpufreq
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 8
             slot: L1 Cache
             size: 32KiB
             capacity: 32KiB
             capabilities: internal write-back
             configuration: level=1
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 9
             slot: L2 Cache
             size: 256KiB
             capacity: 256KiB
             capabilities: pipeline-burst synchronous internal write-back unified
             configuration: level=2
        *-cache:2
             description: L3 cache
             physical id: a
             slot: L3 Cache
             size: 3MiB
             capacity: 8MiB
             capabilities: burst internal write-back unified
             configuration: level=3
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 11
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 4GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: SODIMM Synchronous 667 MHz (1.5 ns)
             product: M471B5773DH0-CH9
             vendor: Samsung
             physical id: 0
             serial: 67294733
             slot: DDRIII 1
             size: 2GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 667MHz (1.5ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: SODIMM Synchronous 533 MHz (1.9 ns)
             vendor: 0000
             physical id: 1
             serial: 00000000
             slot: DDRIII 2
             size: 2GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 533MHz (1.9ns)
     *-pci:0
          description: Host bridge
          product: Core Processor DRAM Controller
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 02
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 02
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:29 memory:f2000000-f23fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:1800(size=8) memory:c0000-dffff
        *-communication:0
             description: Communication controller
             product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 06
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:27 memory:f2727800-f272780f
        *-ide
             description: IDE interface
             product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PT IDER Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.2
             version: 06
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ide pm msi pci_native_mode-only_controller__supports_bus_mastering bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ata_generic latency=0
             resources: irq:18 ioport:1828(size=8) ioport:180c(size=4) ioport:1820(size=8) ioport:1808(size=4) ioport:1810(size=16)
        *-communication:1
             description: Serial controller
             product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset KT Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.3
             version: 06
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: pm msi 16550 cap_list
             configuration: driver=serial latency=0
             resources: irq:17 ioport:1830(size=8) memory:f2724000-f2724fff
        *-network
             description: Ethernet interface
             product: 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 19
             bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
             logical name: enp0s25
             version: 05
             serial: 8c:73:6e:7b:1e:1f
             capacity: 1Gbit/s
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
             configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.12-1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
             resources: irq:30 memory:f2700000-f271ffff memory:f2725000-f2725fff ioport:1840(size=32)
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:22 memory:f2728000-f27283ff
           *-usbhost
                product: EHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.5.13-arch2-1 ehci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 5.05
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=3 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: USB hub
                   product: Integrated Rate Matching Hub
                   vendor: Intel Corp.
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@1:1
                   version: 0.00
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=480Mbit/s
                 *-usb
                      description: Mass storage device
                      product: USB2.0-CRW
                      vendor: Generic
                      physical id: 6
                      bus info: usb@1:1.6
                      version: 38.82
                      serial: 20090516388200000
                      capabilities: usb-2.00 scsi
                      configuration: driver=ums-realtek maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 05
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:28 memory:f2720000-f2723fff
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 6
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:24 ioport:2000(size=4096) memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:c0000000(size=2097152)
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.1
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:25 ioport:3000(size=4096) memory:f2400000-f24fffff ioport:c0200000(size=2097152)
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: AR9287 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
                vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:10:00.0
                logical name: wlp16s0
                version: 01
                serial: b4:74:9f:7a:f1:27
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=5.5.13-arch2-1 firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.96 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                resources: irq:17 memory:f2400000-f240ffff
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:22 memory:f2728400-f27287ff
           *-usbhost
                product: EHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.5.13-arch2-1 ehci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 5.05
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=3 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: USB hub
                   product: Integrated Rate Matching Hub
                   vendor: Intel Corp.
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@2:1
                   version: 0.00
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=8 speed=480Mbit/s
                 *-usb UNCLAIMED
                      description: Smart card reader
                      product: GemPC Express
                      vendor: Gemplus
                      physical id: 2
                      bus info: usb@2:1.2
                      version: 1.00
                      capabilities: usb-2.00
                      configuration: maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1e
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1e.0
             version: a5
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci subtractive_decode bus_master cap_list
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: QM57 Chipset LPC Interface Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
             resources: irq:0
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 6 port SATA AHCI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:26 ioport:1888(size=8) ioport:183c(size=4) ioport:1880(size=8) ioport:1838(size=4) ioport:1860(size=32) memory:f2727000-f27277ff
        *-serial
             description: SMBus
             product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 05
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: driver=i801_smbus latency=0
             resources: irq:18 memory:f2728800-f27288ff ioport:18a0(size=32)
        *-generic
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.6
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
             version: 05
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi cap_list
             configuration: driver=intel ips latency=0
             resources: irq:18 memory:f2726000-f2726fff
     *-pci:1
          description: Host bridge
          product: Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 101
          bus info: pci@0000:ff:00.0
          version: 02
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:2
          description: Host bridge
          product: Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 102
          bus info: pci@0000:ff:00.1
          version: 02
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:3
          description: Host bridge
          product: Core Processor QPI Link 0
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 103
          bus info: pci@0000:ff:02.0
          version: 02
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:4
          description: Host bridge
          product: 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor QPI Physical 0
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 104
          bus info: pci@0000:ff:02.1
          version: 02
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:5
          description: Host bridge
          product: 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor Reserved
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 105
          bus info: pci@0000:ff:02.2
          version: 02
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:6
          description: Host bridge
          product: 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor Reserved
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 106
          bus info: pci@0000:ff:02.3
          version: 02
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
  *-battery
       description: Lithium Ion Battery
       product: CP293550-01
       vendor: FUJITSU
       physical id: 1
       serial: 02A-Z110223000439Z
       slot: Internal Battery
       capacity: 62640mWh
       configuration: voltage=10.8V
  *-scsi
       physical id: 2
       bus info: scsi@8
       logical name: scsi8
       capabilities: scsi-host
       configuration: driver=ums-realtek
```

Comment: One of your RAM sticks is a Samsung, the other is, literally, a no-name, so it's possible that your motherboard won't allow it in slot 0 because that's the one in contact with the RAM bus. If there's a brand sticker on this stick, then maybe it's malfunctioning, or it's counterfeit. Did you run a memtest? Do you get any errors? Plus, the second one, on slot 1, is working underclock compared to the other one. That could indicate a dying stick, or that your bus has a loose wire somewhere.

Comment: The screen does not even light up (it's black) so I can't run any tests or enter bios.

Comment: @Didier, By the way, I just ordered these dual sticks, I hope I didn't wasted my money...
http://www.poweredbymushkin.com/Home/index.php/catalog/memory/essentials/item/229-ddr3-4/298-996644
This is the reason I asked this question too, in order to make sure how to install them properly.

Comment: On a platform like yours, clocking RAM speed to under its sold-for value (1066MHz according to the vendor; 667MHz for one of your sticks, 533MHz for the other) indicates that either the second stick is defective, or counterfeited, or there's a setting to change in your UEFI in terms of memory speed. It should be set at a minimum of 1066MHz, can be pushed to 1333MHz or set to Auto, in which case it'll default to the lowest available clock speed of the two sticks. My opinion: your second stick is defective someway, or comes from bulk vendor that's not referenced by Intel.

Comment: I searched the bios settings one by one and I did not found any options to change the clock speed of the ram. I'm also pretty sure I have the latest bios version.

Comment: Your BIOS version dates back to 2011, according to your screenshots, but if there hasn't been a new release since then, we have to work with that. (Worth checking, though, either on the Phoenix Technologies website, or on Fujitsu's, but to my knowledge, their PC business has gone the way of IBM's: extinct.) Anyway, if you can't set anything from there, then we have to assume that it's automatic, in which case your second stick is the limiting factor here. You can leave the Samsung in slot 0, and the no-name in slot 1, and your PC will work fine, albeit at slower clock speed, right?

Comment: It would also be interesting to know what operating system you run on this PC.

Comment: Yes you're right in everything, also I checked fujitsu's site and I have the latest bios. My OS is linux: Arch Linux distro.

Comment: Is your Arch 32-bit or 64-bit? It shouldn't matter much, but just in case.

Comment: It's Arch 64-bit.

Comment: Then all your RAM should be accounted for, no matter what. I still think this second stick isn't entirely kosher, but I may be mistaken.

Comment: I will write a comment again after I receive and try out the new ones. I just hope they will work... http://www.poweredbymushkin.com/Home/index.php/catalog/memory/essentials/item/229-ddr3-4/298-996644

Comment: Fingers crossed. Have you checked if your platform can accomodate that much RAM in dual-channel with the "sudo dmidecode -t 16" command?

Comment: I can not really understand what the following means:
`Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.6 present.

Handle 0x0011, DMI type 16, 15 bytes
Physical Memory Array
        Location: System Board Or Motherboard
        Use: System Memory
        Error Correction Type: None
        Maximum Capacity: 8 GB
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Number Of Devices: 2`

Comment: It says the max RAM on your machine is 8GB, either under the form of a single 8GB stick (in slot 0, no dual-channel) or 2 x 4GB ("number of devices: 2"). You're good to go!

Comment: I installed the ram and they worked!! Then I disassembly the laptop to clean the CPU, I broke the lock mechanism that keeps the pins stable on the board of the power, reset etc buttons and now the laptop does not even power up... I destroyed it.. I shouldn't mess with that. I tried to stick plastic paper in the pins locker to push them down so they will make contact with the socket, but it doesn't work. Who know's what else I broke during this procedure... 60$ wasted like that...